# Unformatted read/write of derived types containing pointers

Tags: pointers, serialization, fortran

Using Fortran 95.

I need to serialize a complex derived type (containing other derived types) using unformatted write (subsequently use unformatted read to reload it).

Easiest is simply

```
write(lun) myComplexType
```

However this doesn't work because the type contains a pointer. I'm not worried about preserving the pointer (I can separately serialize what it points to and re-establish the pointer on later reload).

Because the derived type's structure is liable to change I want to avoid having to write each element separately, either in the main code or in a defined output procedure.

Is there an easy way to do an unformatted write that ignores the pointer and that doesn't require me to separately address the dozens of other nested data elements - which would give me a maintenance problem?

If there isn't an easy way I may have to hold the pointer in a separate parallel data structure, but I'm not happy with that as I would need to ensure they don't get separated or out of sync when being passed as parameters (the structure in question holds the state of a complex simulation and I really want to keep the entire state in one structure).

The underlying purpose is simply to serialize the simulation state to file at intervals so I can restart the simulation from the serialized dump of the state later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to split out the non-pointer components into their own type, which is then used as the type of a component of another "wrapper" type, that also contains the pointers.

```
TYPE :: non_pointer
  ! Lots of non-pointer components/nested types, etc.
END TYPE non_pointer

TYPE :: wrapper
  TYPE(non_pointer) :: stuff
  TYPE(xxx), POINTER :: ptr_comp
END TYPE wrapper
```

Your input/output statements then reference the `stuff` component.

```
TYPE(wrapper) :: my_simulation_state

WRITE (unit) my_simulation_state%stuff
```

Procedures generally operate on objects of the wrapper type, this still keeps the "entire state" in the one structure.

Whether it is suitable depends on how easy it is to extract the pointer components from the existing type.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Ian's answer, it might be interesting to also consider inheritance to separate non-pointer and pointer data and write only the base part. (But in practice the composition approach may be more flexible and recommended (e.g.[this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance))).

```
program main
    implicit none

    type simbase_t  !! includes all non-pointer data
        integer :: n = 0
        real    :: x = 0.0
    endtype

    type, extends(simbase_t) :: sim_t  !! for additional pointer data
        integer, pointer :: p => null()
    endtype

    type(sim_t) :: sim1, sim2

    sim1 % n = 100
    sim1 % x = 1.23

    print *, "sim2 (before) = ", sim2 % simbase_t

    write( 100 ) sim1 % simbase_t
    rewind( 100 )
    read( 100 ) sim2 % simbase_t

    print *, "sim2 (after)  = ", sim2 % simbase_t    
end program
```

Result:

```
 sim2 (before) =            0   0.0000000    
 sim2 (after)  =          100   1.2300000
```

Comment: One could even (and in IanH's answer) have user-defined I/O so that `write(100) sim1` works exactly as expected (with the procedures just doing `write(unit,...) obj%simbase_t`.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I think that separation of pointer and non-pointer elements within a wrapper is probably the way I'll have to go.